# Prove that the identity matrix is the only matrix such that $IA = A$ for all $A.$

Tags: matrices, proof-writing

How do I prove that $I$ is the only matrix such that $IA = A$ for all $A?$ I keep getting tripped up on the index notation. Thanks!

Comment: We already know that the "identity matrix" does the job. Now let $J$ be an $n\times n$ matrix such that $JA=A$ for all $n\times n$ matrices $A$. Then plugging $A=I$, we have $J=JI=I$.

Answer (score 3):

Copy of the proof; *Group has one identity*

Let there be another matrix $I'$ such that $I'A=A$ for all $A$.

Then $II'=I'$ (putting $A=I'$) and also $II'=I'I=I$ (second equality occurs putting $A=I$).

Thus from both we get $I=I'$. Hence $I$ is only such matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You are using index notation and want to prove $BA=A\Rightarrow B = I$ ? Here's how:

Well,

$$b_{ij}A_{jk}=A_{ik}$$

$$b_{ij}A_{jk}=\delta_{ij}A_{jk}$$

$$(b_{ij}-\delta_{ij})A_{jk}=0$$

Since $A$ is arbitrary, we must have that the bracket is zero, and thus we have proven the claim.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: It turns out, if you had made your request of "index notation" clearer (perhaps with an example or with the first line of working), then you would have gotten more relevant answers.